# ProcessBuilder with GIT command gives no result

Tags: java, git, processbuilder

I try using the Process Builder to execute a git command.
But it does not seem to work any command.

`git log` gives me the right result.

`git shortlog -s` but ends in a TimeOut!

Both commands run in a terminal provide the correct result!
I have tested on Win and Mac.

Does anyone have any idea how I can debug this, or where my mistake is?

Or maybe a different solution?
The aim is to read out the committer to a specific file in a git repository.

The fact Git command is `git shortlog -s -p FeilePath` ?

My Test Code:

```
 @Test
    public void testCommandListDir() {

        File execDir = new File("./");
        String returnValue = "";

        try {
            returnValue = runCommand(execDir, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, "git", "log");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertTrue(returnValue.contains("+ try and error for git shortlog"));
    }


    @Test
    public void testCommandGitShortlog() {

        File execDir = new File("./");
        String returnValue = "";

        try {
            returnValue = runCommand(execDir, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, "git", "shortlog", "-s");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertTrue(returnValue.equals(""));
    }

    public static String runCommand(File directory, long timeout, TimeUnit unit, String... command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command)
                .redirectErrorStream(true).directory(directory);


        Process p = pb.start();

        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        InputStream es = p.getErrorStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(es));
        String in;

        boolean timeOut = false;


        if (!p.waitFor(timeout, unit)) {
            //timeout - kill the process.
            p.destroy(); // consider using destroyForcibly instead
            timeOut = true;
        }

        if (timeOut) {
            //write time out msg
            sb.append("RunCommand time out! after " + timeout + " " + unit.toString() + "\n");
            sb.append("     directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
            sb.append("     command: " + command + "\n");
        } else {
            while ((in = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(in + "\n");
            }

            while ((in = bre.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(in + "\n");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Reading the output of a command **after** it has finished (i.e. after calling `waitFor`) is very likely to break at some point, because it depends on the *entire* output of that application fitting into whichever buffers the OS and/or JVM naturally put there (and the totality of those filters tends to be rather small). So whenever your output exceeds more than a few lines of text, this code will break (because the output call of the process you start will block until you read and your code doesn't read until the output process quits: a classical deadlock).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying your goal is `git blame <filepath>`.

I would suggest the Git API for Java (JGit). In this [cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook), there are several examples on how to get started.

More specifically, you can blame a given file in a given commit, like this:

```
private BlameResult blameCommit(String path, RevCommit commitToBlame) throws GitAPIException {
    BlameCommand blamer = new BlameCommand(<yourRepository>);
    ObjectId commitToBlameID = commitToBlame.getId();
    blamer.setStartCommit(commitToBlameID);
    blamer.setFilePath(path);
    return blamer.call();
}
```

... or recursively in a given time range, like this:

```
public List<Blame> recuriveBlame(String path, RevCommit beginRevision, RevCommit endRevision) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
   if (path == null
            || beginRevision == null
            || endRevision == null) {
        return null;
    }

    List<Blame> result = new ArrayList<Blame>();
    try (RevWalk rw = new RevWalk(this.repo)) {
        rw.markStart(rw.parseCommit(this.beginRevision));
        rw.markUninteresting(rw.parseCommit(this.endRevision));
        for (RevCommit curr; (curr = rw.next()) != null;){
            result.add(new Blame(curr, blameCommit(path, curr)));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

... and get the committer of a given line of given file in a given commit, like [this](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowBlame.java):

```
public void printCommitter(Repository repo, ObjectID commitID, String filename){
   int lines = countFiles(repos, commitID, filename);
   for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
       PersonIdent committer = blame.getSourceCommitter(i);
       System.out.println("Committer of the line: " + i + ": " + committer.getName());
   }
}
```

ps: Be aware that you may need to make small changes to run this code. For instance, `countFiles(...)` is [here](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowBlame.java).

Answer (score 0):

The issue with git shortlog is this from man page (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog)

> If no revisions are passed on the command line and either standard input is not a terminal or there is no current branch, git shortlog will output a summary of the log read from standard input, without reference to the current repository.

The command `git shortlog -s -p FeilePath` does not include a revision range so git will try to read from its `stdin`, and the java program is not providing anything to read.

In a similar thing I'm doing, including `HEAD`, `--all` or `--branches main` all worked, as would, I assume, any valid revision range.